# How to reduce time to initialize page objects in Page Object Model Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

In my Selenium Automation Framework, we have to initialize page classes for each and every `@Test` methods. It is taking too much time to load all the page classes for each method.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public void presetup() {
    class1 = CustomPageFactory.initElements(Class1.class);
    class2 = CustomPageFactory.initElements(Class2.class);
    class3 = CustomPageFactory.initElements(Class3.class);
}
```

This `presetup()` method will execute before each `@Test` method. We are having around ~15 classes to initialize for each Test.It effects my overall test execution time. Especially When we run the cases on Grid environment it is taking huge time.

Do we have any workaround to reduce execution time in Page Object Model?

Any alternative way to initialize page objects where it takes less time?

Comment: PageFactory class just creates proxies, it does not interact with the page. It should not be the cause for the huge time delay. What does the CustomPageFactory class do? Also does every test need all 15 pageobjects? Why not initialize it once in a BeforeClass methods and reuse for all tests?

Comment: CustomPageFactory will proxies all webelements of the page class. We should not keep them at class level, becuase webdriver instance will opened and closed for each Test. If we keep at @BeforeClass facing NullPointerException.

Comment: Are you sure the delay is with the page class initialization? Maybe the delays arise from initializing WebDriver instances for each test method.

Comment: I tried to run the script in debug mode as well, it seems the problem with page initialization.

Comment: @PrasadPasupuleti Please edit your question and show us what `CustomPageFactory.initElements()` looks like ? The default implementation of `org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory` merely uses reflection to load up classes, instantiate it and set its fields with decorators which would be invoked when accessed. It should not take time such that it starts becoming evident. And oh btw, grid execution has got nothing to do with this.Your Grid execution is perhaps becoming slower due to network latencies perhaps.